# PHPMyAdmin 4.0.5 - Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available

Tags: phpmyadmin

I see this warning in PHPMyAdmin 4.0.5
"does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available."
In PHPMyAdmin 3.5.1 these options appear correctly using the same database.
Can fix this? How?
thanks in advance
Fabián.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To fix this, pick a suitable column(s) in your table and create a unique index on it (or on them). Version 4.0 added this verification to avoid other problems when not the intended row is modified or deleted.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key.

[EDIT] However, version 4.5.0 contains an improvement in this regard, see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11061

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to assign a primary key to the table. Just click on the 'Structure' tab when viewing the table you are trying to edit, choose a field you want to be the primary key and there is a button to assign it as the primary key in one of the columns. Go back to the browse tab and you should now be able to edit the table.