# Why is the phpmyadmin search saying there is not unique column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm using the following SQL code to search through my MySQL database:

```
SELECT a.* FROM clients a JOIN (SELECT email, COUNT(*) FROM clients GROUP BY email HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b ON a.email = b.email ORDER BY a.email
```

. However, after my search, the rows come up and it says: `Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.`

Yet the column clientID, which is marked as a primary key is there, but I still cannot edit. What is the problem?

[image: This is what my clientID structure is.]

This is my clientID structure.

[image: This is what the search returns]

This is what the search returns. Also before anyone mentions it, the passwords are hashed.

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the join is your issue.

Comment: I believe it's referring to the unique index, which is missing from one or more rows (resulting from your join). See this question: [PHPMyAdmin 4.0.5 - Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748073/phpmyadmin-4-0-5-grid-edit-checkbox-edit-copy-and-delete-features-are-not-a/18748488)

Comment: @EternalHour but clientID column is already set as the primary index. Which is unique no?

Comment: @TimRumit yes, but it's _not_ (or potentially not) unique in the context of the query results (because of the join, as EternalHour mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the SQL query to the following:

`select * from clients a where ( email ) in ( select email from clients group by email having count(*) > 1 )`

Now it works with editing and deleting etc..